# what is the query in MYSQL to copy the content of a attribute to another attribute if i am having two different database and table

Tags: mysql, database, insert, copy

i needed a query in MYSQL which can copy the data only from one attribute which in a table of a different database to a different attribute of a table of a different database.

example:

```
     from : ibm (database1)-> customer (table1)->fullname (attribute1)
     to   : infosis (database2)-> user (table2)->name (attribute2)
```

note: here attribute1 and attribute2 both has data in them

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways 
1) Import data into SQL script and replace the content keyword of database name, table name and field name

2) Export all the data into a csv and create a script to upload CSV to get all the data into an array, then by a script you can insert it into your new data base no matter what new structure you are having.

3) Create two db connection to your two different databases then make a PHP script which will get data from old db lets say db1->table1 and insert it to db2->table2 by using two different connections.